# Run a Python code over a bunch of files in a folder at a time in linux

Tags: python, linux, csv

I have the following code

```
    import sys
    import glob

    for filename in glob.glob(sys.argv[1]):
       file = open(filename)
       data = [line.rstrip() + "," + filename for line in file]
       file.close()

    file = open(filename, "w")
    file.write("\n".join(data))
    file.close()
```

Now I would like to execute it on all the files contained in a folder named "CSV". I am working on UBUNTU 12.04 and a newbie to linux.

All the help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you don't really want to just overwrite the last filename you got from the glob, so your indentation is broken. Could you explain what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: My question is: How to execute the above code saved in fnadder.py to all the files saved in director without any extension. The code is basically adding the filename to the lsat column of the CSV file. Thansk

Comment: the code is working fine when i execute it single like:      abdullah@idiotbox:~/Desktop/THCM/job/test$ python fnadder.py 075C-0001    but there are some 200 files and I would like to do it in a one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also simply let the shell do the globbing for you:

```
python myscript.py path/to/files/*.CSV
```

Then in your python script:

```
[...]
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    # do stuff...
```

This would however not work in Windows, since you would only receive one argument "path/to/files/*.CSV" in sys.argv.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but if you want to loop through a lot of files in a folder you can use the linux `find` command.

An example in your situation would be:

```
cd /path/to/folder/CSV
find . -name *.csv -exec your_python_script.py {} \;
```

This will find all the `.csv` files and run your python script on each one.

Make sure you have `#!/bin/env python` at the top of your file and run `sudo chmod +x your_python_script.py` to make it executable.

If you don't have the `.csv` extension then you can do the following:

```
cd /path/to/folder/CSV
find . -exec your_python_script.py {} \;
```

Though be warned - this will run on **every file** in the directory - CSV or otherwise.

Also, if I understand your script correctly (it's just appending the filename to the final column), try this:

```
#!/bin/env python

import sys
import csv

filename=sys.argv[1]
output_filename='new-'+filename
output_rows = []
with open(filename, 'r') as inputfile:
    with open(output_filename) as outputfile:
        r = csv.reader(inputfile)
        w = csv.writer(outputfile, lineterminator='\n')
        for input_row in r:
            output_row=input_row.append(filename)
            output_rows.append(output_row)

        w.writerows(output_rows)
```

save that as `test_python_script.py` in your `CSV` folder. Then run:

```
cd /path/to/folder/CSV
chmod +x test_python_script.py
find . -exec test_python_script.py {} \;
```

Comment: I have removed the extension .csv as I am going to add the file name at the last column. So the file names are: 0750-0004, 0750-0002, and so on around 200. Thanks for the kind concern and valuable time.